# How can I get the results of a JSON POST back

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm posting this JSON from a form page

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function poster()
        {
            var dataToPost = {grant_type: "password", username: dojo.byId("username").value, password: dojo.byId("password").value, redirect_uri: "http://localhost/default.html"};
            var xhrArgs =
            {
                url: "https://localhost/api/did/authenticate?client_id=12345",
                handleAs: 'json',
                postData: dojo.toJson(dataToPost),
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8", "Accept" : "application/json" },
                load: function(data, args) 
                {
                    alert("Data = " + data);
                },
                error: function(error, args)
                {
                    alert("Error! " + error); 
                }
            }
            dojo.rawXhrPost(xhrArgs);
        }
    </script>
```

But I'm not able to get the JSON results from said POST. How can I get those results? Please help. The data I get on the load function is null

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous; `result = dojo.rawXhrPost` will never give you the results.  The result of the AJAX call are available in the `load:` function.

Comment: data in the load function is returning empty (null)

Comment: What should your server return? My guess is either you have a silent error on the server side that returns nothing. Then you'd have a status 200 OK, with no data. try to put some try catch or echo here and there :)

Comment: use etherial or fiddler to confirm that there is actually something sent in response to the ajax call.

Comment: can you try success instead of load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that what I was trying to do is not possible in JavaScript since I'm trying to do it from one domain into another... so the cross-domain implementation is not possible, unless I use an embedded flash object, or a proxy pass in my server. thanks for the help though...

Answer (score 0):

The script at `https://localhost/api/did/authenticate` needs to `print` or `echo` or `write` or otherwise return the JSON as text as it exits.